# How to change php via ajax for specified user only

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, calendar

I need a hand cause I run out of ideas.

I have a ajax script and php script, logic is as followes:
1. PHP script is making a calendar with marked bookings and send it to HTML page,
2. On HTML page user can click on button "Next month" and it sends a ajax request to php script.
3. PHP is doing month++ and sending results.

This work only one time due to reset in php script with every request.
month++ it's always only one month forward.

Do you have any ideas how to shuffle through calendar?

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once ("config.php");

/* Fields counter */
$FieldsNo=1;

/* Getting today's date*/ 
$date = date("d.n.Y");

/* date slicing */
$str = explode(".", $date);
    $day = $str[0];
    $month = $str[1];
    $year = $str[2];
    $gmonth = $month;
    $gyear = $year;

if (isset($_POST['month'])) {

    $month++;
}
require_once ("arrays.php");


/* operation with calendar */
$daysinmonth=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
$julianDayCount=cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, 1, $year);
$dayOfWeek=jddayofweek($julianDayCount, 0);
$fullies = $daysinmonth;
/* counting amount of empty fields */
switch ($dayOfWeek) {
case 0:
    $empties= 6;
    break;
case 1:
    $empties= 0;
    break;
case 2:
    $empties=1;
    break;
case 3:
    $empties = 2;
    break;
case 4:
    $empties = 3;
    break;
case 5:
    $empties = 4;
    break;
case 6:
    $empties = 5;
    break;
}
/* month translation*/
if ($language == "pl") {
    include("months_pl.php"); 
} else {
    include("months_eng.php"); 
}
/* echoing calendar base */
echo $monthn;
echo $day;
echo "<br>";
if ($language == "pl") {
    include("days_pl.php"); 
} else {
    include("days_eng.php"); 
}

/* first loop - empty fields */
if ($today) {
    include("calendarloopt.php"); 
} else {
    include("calendarloop.php"); 
} 
echo "</tr></tbody></table>";

echo json_encode($loadout);

?>
```

HTML/AJAX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#next").click(function() {
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
    type     : "POST",
    url      : "calendar.php",
    data     : {
            month: 'next'
    },
    success: function(html){

$("#loadplace").html(html);

},
    error:    function(error) {
        //ten fragment wykona się w przypadku BŁĘDU
    }
});
            return jqXHR.responseText;
            });
            });
</script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="next" value="Next Month"/>


        <div id="loadplace" align="right" width="400" height ="400">

<?php
            include 'calendar.php';
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reset the value in the PHP page each time it runs.

Use a [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) variable instead (and set to a reasonable default if the session variable was not yet set).

Also, your current code will fail when you try to increment December.  Have a look at the PHP [Datetime::add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) function

Comment: I need to do some research about sessions, yet great thanks.
Unfortunately I can't vote you up :<

Answer (score 0):

You should do the month incrementing in the JavaScript and not in the PHP.

An AJAX request should return a value consistent with the parameters it has been passed. The way you want to implement it, it would also depend on an *internal* variable.

Your actual script also has little flexibility. It can only return the next month. What if you'd like to be able to return the previous month, or a specific month in the future?

In my opinion, you should change your AJAX script either to return the calendar for a specific month, or to return the calendar for the month following (or preceding) a specific month.